# How to confirm if all the cores are used by openmp in a multi core system?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm learning openMP using c++ language. I'm sure that in the parallel region of the code, the specified number of threads are spawned. But it is unclear to me whether the threads are running on all the available cores. Is there a method to confirm that? I'm running the code on ubuntu12.04 compiled using g++.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @PoojaNilangekar I have edited the post. I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `htop` using `sudo apt-get install htop`. After this you could  run the command `htop` to monitor the CPU and memory usage of all the processes running on your machine.

Comment: I'm currently not using computationally intensive code. So I could not see any difference in the core usage by running htop. Is there any other method?

Comment: Okay in which case, inside the parallel code print `sched_getcpu()`. This will print the id of the CPU on which the thread is running.